# Cannot retrieve attribute value from geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver

Iam new to geoserver. I have created shape file of my district and added certain attributes like covid count, covid zone , district name etc related to COVID . I have loaded this to postgis database and I could see attributes also in table .But when I try to retrieve the feature using postman . Attribute values are not retrieved. Can anyone help

Below is my request
**http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/DistrictWpc/datastores/district_store/featuretypes/ernakulam.json**

Response is
{
    "featureType": {
        "name": "ernakulam",
        "nativeName": "ernakulam",
        "namespace": {
            "name": "DistrictWpc",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/DistrictWpc.json"
        },
        "title": "ernakulam",
        "keywords": {
            "string": [
                "features",
                "ernakulam"
            ]
        },
        "srs": "EPSG:404000",
        "nativeBoundingBox": {
            "minx": 76.1618881225586,
            "maxx": 76.6080093383789,
            "miny": 9.63820648193359,
            "maxy": 10.1869020462036
        },
        "latLonBoundingBox": {
            "minx": 76.1618881225586,
            "maxx": 76.6080093383789,
            "miny": 9.63820648193359,
            "maxy": 10.1869020462036,
            "crs": "EPSG:4326"
        },
        "projectionPolicy": "FORCE_DECLARED",
        "enabled": true,
        "store": {
            "@class": "dataStore",
            "name": "DistrictWpc:district_store",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/DistrictWpc/datastores/district_store.json"
        },
        "serviceConfiguration": false,
        "maxFeatures": 0,
        "numDecimals": 0,
        "padWithZeros": false,
        "forcedDecimal": false,
        "overridingServiceSRS": false,
        "skipNumberMatched": false,
        "circularArcPresent": false,
        "attributes": {
            "attribute": [
                {
                    "name": "id",
                    "minOccurs": 0,
                    "maxOccurs": 1,
                    "nillable": true,
                    "binding": "java.lang.Long"
                },
                {
                    "name": "district",
                    "minOccurs": 0,
                    "maxOccurs": 1,
                    "nillable": true,
                    "binding": "java.lang.String"
                },
                {
                    "name": "count",
                    "minOccurs": 0,
                    "maxOccurs": 1,
                    "nillable": true,
                    "binding": "java.lang.Long"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zone",
                    "minOccurs": 0,
                    "maxOccurs": 1,
                    "nillable": true,
                    "binding": "java.lang.String"
                },
                {
                    "name": "geom",
                    "minOccurs": 0,
                    "maxOccurs": 1,
                    "nillable": true,
                    "binding": "org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiPolygon"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GeoServer's REST API](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/) is used for administrative tasks and as such does not provide a way to see the actual data you have stored in the database, just the details of how GeoServer is connecting to the database and some metadata about the store.

To access the actual data you need to use the WFS endpoint which is described by the [OGC WES Specification](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wfs) and described in the [GeoServer manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html).

If you must have REST access to the features you could use the **experimental** [OGC Features API module](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/ogc-api/index.html) to do this.